# Determining the hostname/IP address from the MX record in PHP

Tags: php, dns

have a basic email domain validation script that takes a user's email domain, resolves the IP address from that and then checks that against various published blacklists.  Here is how I am determining the IP:

```
$domain = substr(strchr($email, '@'), 1);
$ip     = gethostbyname($domain);
```

The problem is that some email address domains, such as soandso@alumni.example.net, use an MX record rather than an A record, so using gethostbyname('alumni.example.net') will fail to resolve.  I know when a user's email is using an MX in the email itself by using the PHP checkdnsrr function, but once at that stage am a little stuck as to how to proceed.

In theory, I could parse out the 'root' domain, i.e. 'example.net' and check it, but I've not found reliable regex that can handle this task when the user could easily have an email the format of user@corp.example.co.uk...

So, any suggestions on how to best tackle this??

Comment: Note that the MX record will point to the machine(s) that are able to *receive* mail for a given domain, whereas IP blacklists are generally going to list the IP addresses that *send* mail, which may not be the same.

Comment: Exactly David.  Using the dns_get_record() solution below, I am simply being returned a list of receiving machines for alumni.example.net...  when it would be the IP for example.net that would be blacklisted.

Comment: Any host can send mail for any domain. What you could do is check SPF records. SPF records say which hosts are allowed to send mail for a particular domain. But of course they are optional, and checking them (by receiving mailservers) is optional.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using gethostbyname, use [dns_get_record](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php), something like `dns_get_record($domain,DNS_MX)`. See the docs for how the return values are structured.

Comment: Hi Ycros, thanks for the response.  My issue is that when I encounter an email domain that is in fact an MX record rather than an A record, dns_get_record() for that domain is simply returning the machines that can handle the mail.  I need to somehow resolve the MX to the root domain so I can check that IP against the blacklists.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Arr = dns_get_record('ford.com' , DNS_MX);


$count = count($Arr);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

    echo $i.'-'.$Arr[$i]['target'].'-'.gethostbyname($Arr[$i]['target']).'-'.$Arr[$i]['ttl'].'<br/>';
}
```

I got the result with ip address as following order(Pref, host, ip, ttl).

```
0-cluster4a.us.messagelabs.com-85.158.139.103-453
1-cluster4.us.messagelabs.com-216.82.242.179-453
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably

```
if (!getmxrr($host, $result)) {
  $result=array($host);
}
```

Then loop over the results, calling gethostbyname() and checking that none are blacklisted (or you could pick the result with the lowest weight, but that could be easily used to circumvent the blacklist).

I'd question the usefulness of blacklisting a destination; DNS spam blacklists are usually made for blacklisting sources.

Comment: THanks tc.  Correct, I am trying to check the mail source, no the destination.  Typically I can look at the email domain and use that as a source, which I can check easily against the blacklists.  The problem is when the user email domain is an MX... how to trace the MX reliably back to a source domain so that I can check that domain is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do *source* validation based solely on someone's e-mail address, because (in general) any party anywhere on the internet can send any e-mail with anyone else's e-mail address in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you can only check atleast one mx records is available for the given domain. Code is not tested with multiple domains.

```
function mxrecordValidate($email){
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
        $arr= dns_get_record($domain,DNS_MX);
        if($arr[0]['host']==$domain&&!empty($arr[0]['target'])){
                return $arr[0]['target'];
        }
}
$email= 'user@radiffmail.com';

if(mxrecordValidate($email)) {
        echo('This MX records exists; I will accept this email as valid.');
}
else {
        echo('No MX record exists;  Invalid email.');
}
```

If find any improvement in this function, comments are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$result = shell_exec ('host -t MX '.$domain);

var_dump ($result);
```

or

```
exec ('host -t MX '.$domain, $result = array ());

var_dump ($result);
```

You will get list of MX records, you can parse it and check each record with gethostbyname().

**Edit**

dns_get_record() mentioned by Ycros will be better.